# how to fix Nextjs13 could not find the module app-router.js#

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, app-router

after running `npx create-next-app@latest`, I said yes to use App Router(as it recommends to use it). but after that when I run `npm run dev` I'm getting the following errors.

Uncaught Error: `Could not find the module "node_modules\next\dist\client\components\app-router.js#" in the React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler`.

The above error occurred in the `<ServerRoot>` component

I tried to install app router explicitly but still no luck.

Comment: When putting large blocks of code, such as your error, you can put triple backticks (this: ```) above and below the code to display it properly in a more readable way. 

Comment: Thank you Robert but there's no code in my question

Comment: I meant to put code, or other things such as your error.  It's not strictly for code, it can also be just for computer or site messages; either that or putting it in a blockquote would be a good way to set it apart in your situation.